# Не срабатывает .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Все правила для .htaccess я брал из интернета, но вроде они верны.

Хочу что бы было перенаправление вида РутПапка/app/frontController.php Но без упоминания путей в строке браузера (убрать app/frontController), в правилах htaccess файлов это прописано.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

.htaccess в данной (рут) папке такой

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^.*$ /app/frontController.php

</IfModule>
```

Папка app

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и её .htaccess

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* frontController.php [L]
```

EDIT2: Обрабатывается и 1ый htaccess и 2ой htaccess только правила у них не работают. Обработка htaccess в конфигурации апача включена. Почему-то при написании только названия рут-папки в строку браузера открывается директория рут-папка/app/ в конфигурации апача её не упоминается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так соедините 2 правила. А ещё можно в apache сразу сделать каталог app рутовым.

Comment: А ещё может в апаче отключена обработка htaccess

Comment: Извините что удаляю комментарии, но каждый раз ситуация координально меняется и не понятно из-за чего. Обрабатывается и 1ый htaccess и 2ой htaccess только правила у них не работают. Обработка htaccess в конфигурации апача включена. Почему-то при написании только названия рут-папки в строку браузера открывается директория рут-папка/app/ в конфигурации апача её не упоминается.

Comment: Я удалил эти htaccessы и зашел в рутПапку, все равно ссылка вида рутПапка/app

Comment: Попробовал перенести проект в другую папку убрав htaccessы, Проблема с автоматическим появлением пути /app пропала. Добавил их снова с теми же правилами 1ый htaccess работает, 2ой нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переместил свой проект в другую папку. Написал то же самое что и сверху в .htaccessах, но добавил в 1ый htaccess строчку DirectoryIndex frontcontroller.php и оно заработало. Не думал что апачу все равно на указанные файлы из htaccess... Видимо я чего-то не понимаю, но кажется Апач предпочитает только то что будет записано в DirectoryIndex.